# Trying to set up a quiz which gets the correct images from S3 bucket for the correct questions

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, aws-sdk-js

I need help with the quiz I am creating, I am new to Vue.js so probably not the neatest code at the minute. But I need to link the S3 bucket to the code and then get the correct images in the img div. I have linked AWS to my database already using Lambda functions, amplify, API gateway and Dyanmo DB but just need help fetching and pushing images to the S3 bucket.

Any help would be much appreciated!!

```
<template >
    <div class="quiz">
    <div class= "Quiz_box">

        <div class="title" ref="questions">
        <img src="" alt="Image_question" id="Image_question" class="Image_question"> IMG HERE

        <div class="timer_text" id="timer"> </div>

        </div>    

    <div class="buttons_border">
        <div class= "answer11" id="answer1" @click="selected_answer1">
        {{currentQuestion.option1}}
        </div>
        <div class= "answer21" id="answer2" @click="selected_answer2" >
        {{currentQuestion.option2}}
        </div>
        <div class= "answer31" id="answer3" @click="selected_answer3" >
        {{currentQuestion.option3}}
        </div>
        <div class= "answer41" id="answer4" @click="selected_answer4"  >
        {{currentQuestion.option4}}
        </div>
    </div> 

      <div id="NoAnswer" class="NoAnswer_Text"> </div>
      <div>

        <button class="submit" @click="handleButton"> Submit </button>

      </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 </template>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "need help fetching and pushing images to the S3 bucket"?

Comment: For the quiz, I need to have an admin feature where you can upload a image and choose what questions you assign it to. This image needs to go to the S3 bucket on AWS and then be retrieved when the quiz is being played.

Comment: So, with which part of that do you need assistance? Are you having difficult putting content into Amazon S3, or where to store the quiz information, or how to access images and questions during the quiz? What have you tried and what specific issue are you facing?

Comment: I have gone through the AWS tutorial but I get stuck at the end with the code about the SDK- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-photos-view.html#s3-example-photos-view-viewing-album - I need help with the code I have to put in my Vue.js for it to be able to access the S3 bucket and the code for the quiz to know what image to grab. E.g. Quiz1_Image_1 needs to be grabbed when quiz 1 is in play and question 1 is on the screen. Also, if you could help with the code to upload images from the website to the S3 bucket that would be great! Thanks